# Allocating memory dynamically without knowing the size of the string which is going to be entered

Tags: c, pointers, realloc, fgetc, getc

Below is the function which returns a character pointer to a string which was initialized using `getc(stdin)`- character by character.

1. Is there any flaw in memory allocation method? Is this an efficient way when we don't know the size of the string which is going to be entered, if not please explain.
2. Using `getc(stdin)` --will it lead to buffer overflow???()
3. If I must not use `getc(stdin)`, what will help me achieve my goal in a more efficient way?

Code so far:

```
char *getstring()
{
  char *str = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
  int size = 0, index = 0;
  int ch = -1;
  int length=0;
  while (ch!=0) 
  {
    ch = getc(stdin);

    if (ch == '\n')
    {   
        ch = 0;
    }

    if (size <= index) 
    {
        size += 15;
        tmp = (char*)realloc(str, size);
        if (!tmp) 
        {
            free(str);
            str = NULL;    
        }
        str = tmp;
    }
    str[index++] = ch;
  }

  if(size==index)
  {
    return str;
  }
  else if(index<size)
  {
    length=strlen(str);
    tmp = (char*)realloc(str,(length+1));
    str[index]='\0';
    //cout<<"length:"<<length;
    str=tmp;
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: What is the variable `ch`?

Comment: It is an integer, getc returns an integer

Comment: Your code does not handle EOF.

Comment: `str` is NULL if `realloc` fails, `str[index++] = ch;` => `NULL[index++] = ch;`

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the wheel: use [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Example (from same URL):

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int
   main(void)
   {
       FILE *stream;
       char *line = NULL;
       size_t len = 0;
       ssize_t read;

       stream = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
       if (stream == NULL)
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

       while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
           printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
           printf("%s", line);
       }

       free(line);
       fclose(stream);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Comment: might want to fix the int main line. :)

Comment: Note that POSIX systems should not require `_GNU_SOURCE` to provide access to `getline()`.  You might need to set `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before the first header is included to see the declaration of `getline()`, though.

Comment: @MartinTörnwall it's on two lines. not a big deal

Comment: @user3711622 For declarations with a lot of tokens before the actual function name, or complex return types, it can be nice to put the function name on a new line - makes it easier to spot when looking through a large body of code. That said, I did not write said example.

Comment: That, and you can regexp-search for `^<function name>`. While I've rarely seen it in other languages, this is a very common formatting pattern in C.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there any flaw in memory allocation method?"* Yes, when the reallocation fails, you free the previous memory pointer, assign `NULL` to it, then overwrite it with `tmp`, which has the value `NULL`, and then plough on using a `NULL` pointer.

```
if (size <= index) 
{
    size += 15;
    tmp = (char*)realloc(str, size);
    if (!tmp)                   // <--- NULL!
    {
        free(str);
        str = NULL;    
    }
    str = tmp;                  // <--- NULL!
}
str[index++] = ch;              // <--- NULL!
```

But if `realloc` fails you have little choice but to abandon the task in hand gracefully.

Also if you allow for the 0-terminator at the same time, you'll save several messy lines of code and another reallocation. And you don't always insert the `'\0'`.

```
if (size <= index+1)            // allow room for string terminator
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY only just noticed your comment.